# Load external swf using binary socket

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, binary, load, flash

is it possible to load a swf into another swf using a binary socket instead of the traditional AS3 Loader class? Would you share some code or pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be a problem. However, you will still need to use the Loader class, but you won't need to make any calls to a web server with it, which is what I assume you want to avoid.

Take a look at [Loader.loadBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29) and the [examples for connecting to a Socket server](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#includeExamplesSummary).